# What is the limit of the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$, given that $1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} + ... + \dfrac{1}{n} - a_n \ln n$ is bounded.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers, such that the sequence:

$$1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} + ... + \dfrac{1}{n} - a_n \ln n$$

(for $n \ge 1$) is bounded. What is the limit of the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$?

I found this problem in a textbook and thought that it looks interesting. How should I approach something like this?

Comment: What do you know about the growth of the series?

Comment: Does the sequence $a_n$ necessarily have a limit?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant.

Comment: @herbsteinberg If it doesn't have a limit, then $\forall \varepsilon >0, \forall N, \exists n>N$ such that $|a_n-1|>\varepsilon$

Comment: @saulspatz Well, if you mean what do I know in terms of monotony, I don't think I can conclude that the sequence is increasing or decreasing without knowing if the terms of sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$ are positive or negative, which I don't know. Am I wrong? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @herbsteinberg The sequence $a_n$ can also have $+ \infty$ as its limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preliminaries**

Defining the [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)
$$
H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\tag1
$$
and noticing that for $x\in[n,n+1]$, we have $\frac1{n+1}\le\frac1x\le\frac1n$, we get
$$
\overbrace{\ \ \frac1{n+1}\ \ \vphantom{\int^{n+1}}}^{H_{n+1}-H_n}\le\overbrace{\int_n^{n+1}\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x}^{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}\le\overbrace{\quad\ \frac1n\quad\ \vphantom{\int^{n+1}}}^{H_n-H_{n-1}}\tag2
$$
The left-hand inequality shows that $H_{n+1}-\log(n+1)$ is decreasing.
The right-hand inequality shows that $H_n-\log(n+1)$ is increasing.
Together, these show that
$$
\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}(H_n-\log(n))\tag3
$$
exists and is between $H_0-\log(1)=0$ and $H_1-\log(1)=1$.

---

**The Limit**

We are given that
$$
H_n-a_n\log(n)=H_n-\log(n)-(a_n-1)\log(n)\tag4
$$
is bounded, say in $[L,M]$. Then, from what was said in the Preliminaries,
$$
\gamma\le H_n-\log(n)\le1\tag5
$$
and therefore,
$$
\frac{\gamma-M}{\log(n)}\le a_n-1\le\frac{1-L}{\log(n)}\tag6
$$
which, upon taking the limit, gives
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1\tag7
$$

Comment: Can you please explain how did you get the inequality from point $(2)$?

Comment: @user1502: I have added a bit of explanation before $(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Simple pair of diagrams shows this general fact:

if we have $f(x) > 0$ but $f'(x) < 0,$  then

$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  f(j) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  f(x) \; dx   $$

Probably need to start with $a=2,$ with $b=n$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}.$  Then add a $1$ 
$$ 1 + \int_2^{n+1} \; \frac{1}{x} \;  dx \;  < \; 1 + \sum_{j=2}^n \;   \frac{1}{j} \; < \;  1 + \int_{1}^n \;   \frac{1}{x} \; dx   $$

Often $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j}$ is called $H_n$

Answer (score 1):

You want
$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{k}
- a_n \ln n
=O(1)
$.

Since
$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{k}
=\ln(n)+O(1)
$,
you want
$\ln(n)+O(1)
- a_n \ln n
=O(1)
$
or
$(a_n-1)\ln(n)
=O(1)
$.

This requires
$a_n = 1+O(\dfrac1{\ln(n)})
$
so
$a_n \to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is that the sequence $(u_n)_n$ defined by $$
u_n = H_n - a_n \ln n
$$
for $n\geq 1$ (where $H_n$ is the $n$-th [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)) is bounded. I.e., there exists $C>0$ such that, for all $n\geq 1$,
$$
\lvert H_n - a_n \ln n \rvert \leq C
$$
Equivalently,
$$
\forall n\geq 2\,,\quad\left \lvert \frac{H_n}{\ln n} - a_n \right \rvert \leq \frac{C}{\ln n}
$$
and in particular,
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\left \lvert \frac{H_n}{\ln n} - a_n \right \rvert  = 0\,. \tag{1}
$$

But it is well-known that $H_n = \ln n + \gamma + o(1)$ (or, even then, $\displaystyle H_n \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \ln n$ suffices), i.e.,
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{H_n}{\ln n} = 1\,. \tag{2}
$$
Combining (1) and (2) lets you conclude.

Comment: I didn't know about the Harmonic number and after searching Wikipedia I've found that "The harmonic numbers roughly approximate the natural logarithm function and thus the associated harmonic series grows without limit, albeit slowly". Does this "rough" approximation allow us to do what you did in your last line, line $(2)$? I mean, wikipedia says that it "grows without limit".

Comment: @user1502 Yes, see, e.g., the "Calculation" section on Wikipedia.